# SAN Connectivity Extension from one Building to Other with 350 Meters distance Recommendations

Tags: storage, storage-area-network

We have two Data centers, DataCenter-A has all the Backup storage, Datacenter-b has critical servers, We need to backup Datacenter-b Servers via FiberNetwork.

We have Brocade 300 Switches on DC-a & Brocade 6506 Switches on DC-b.

what is the best way to extend the connectivity, will ISL be okay or we need to Extend the Fabric using some other way?

Comment: Actual path might be longer, but 350m is a short distance, multiple ISL link should be OK.

Comment: Will the 2 Active Configurations on each switch will be merged without downtime?

Comment: I’m voting to move this question because to Server Fault where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Actual path might be longer, but 350m is a short distance, multiple ISL link should be OK.

## about downtime.

You usualy define 2 [fabric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched_fabric), in each fabric you proceed with zoning (that is which host are allowed to see each other).

from host to disk relation you define at least two path (wvmware,unix or windows), actual SAN traffic can be round-robin or least traffic.

If a path is dead (due to link failure (rare), gbic failure (less rare) or switch update (twice a year)), packet will be resent on other fabric/other path.

tape drive are connected only on one port, backup software is responsible for retrying.

## merging

Ideally you have config_A1/config_A2 on DC-A, and config_B1/config_B2 on DC-B.

when merging config_X1 there will be a downtime either in config_A1 or config_B1 or both, but you traffic should continue on both config_A2 and config_B2.

Comment: Will i need Extra Licence for ISL?
Will the Firmware of the two Switches should be same,the switches are of different model.

Comment: It is always best to have same up-to-date firmware. as for other question maybe ask your seller's. you have a support contract ? they should be able to answer that.